# Use PollingConditions with return value in Spock?

Tags: unit-testing, groovy, spock

I would like to use `PollingConditions.eventually` to evaluate and return value:

```
    @Shared
    static PollingConditions POLLING_CONDITIONS = new PollingConditions(
            timeout: 30, delay: 1.5, factor: 1.25
    )

    MyResponseContainerDto sendRequestWithRetries(String body, String uri) {
        ExtractableResponse<Response> extractedResponse = null
        POLLING_CONDITIONS.eventually {
           extractedResponse = sendRequest(body, uri).extract()
            assert extractedResponse.statusCode() == 200
        }

        return extractedResponse.as(MyResponseContainerDto.class)
    }

    ValidatableResponse sendRequest(String body, String uri) {
            return RestAssured.given()
                    .contentType(JSON)
                    .body(body)
                    .when()
                    .post("/myApi" + "/" + uri)
                    .then()
                    .log().all()
    }
```

When I try to run the above code I get:

```
Expected a condition, but found an assignment. Did you intend to write '==' ? @ line 42, column 12.
              extractedResponse = sendRequest(body, uri).extract()
              ^
```

Is there a possibility to have an assignment inside the `eventually` block?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an alternative to Marcin's suggestion, a simple workaround would be an [explicit interaction block](https://spockframework.org/spock/docs/2.4-M1/all_in_one.html#_explicit_interaction_blocks):

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q75663270

import spock.lang.Shared
import spock.lang.Specification
import spock.util.concurrent.PollingConditions

class PollingConditionsTest extends Specification {
  @Shared
  PollingConditions POLLING_CONDITIONS = new PollingConditions(
    timeout : 3, delay : 0.2, factor : 1
  )

  def myHelper() {
    def extractedResponse = null
    POLLING_CONDITIONS.eventually {
      interaction {
        extractedResponse = "xxx"
        assert extractedResponse.contains("x")
      }
    }
    extractedResponse
  }

  def test() {
    expect:
    myHelper() == "xxx"
  }
}
```

Please note however that, because the interaction block in your case is not inside `then/expect` but rather in a helper method, you still need the explicit `assert`.

Try it in the [Groovy Web Console](https://gwc-experiment.appspot.com/?g=groovy_2_5&codez=eJxtUcFqAjEQvecrBk8KEqxShYJQsNAKolK9S8jO2mA22SazulL8987qVitrDkOS92bmvZlc6Z3aIiQoow5FtslUJAwyEgN-jyG1_iC_R8_D4aA_6glhstwHgph7vZNWua1cfamAySMgR21SoxUZ7-7xgoyV2jtdhICO5NJba9x24l1iKnYUQlsVIzSANUYCLAldEuGuA_wIgNdaDTQzYbmYzabz981kMX-brqeL-QrG4PDQpLY5H4BMhr4geIFBlwdk1ZGvPdnvQqo0-cCvJyZ2BIcEU8iOH2hzDO3OWcrlk6UGZmPyiWzdRax6FtaeCU1FEvc8j0JZe6yLABjHG-Eafx4v51HhVlmWrSuD54eBmsRq8KQM22yVrU5NP4lbbGSICqldEi_g6hBL3gC9nO__7I9vUk7iJH4BJR7GwQ).

P.S.: A `@Shared` field should not be static. It is Spock's better (with regard to Spock spec lifecycle) alternative to static fields.

Comment: Nice idea with the interactions. It is much cleaner that my approach!

Answer (score 1):

Quoting the [Spock lead maintainer](https://github.com/spockframework/spock/issues/946#issuecomment-435380800) (from 2018, but it seems to still hold):

> (...) assignments (other than to a new variable) in blocks with implicit assertions are forbidden for the expressed purpose of preventing the common mistake of forgetting one = for an equality check, and this will not be changed.

The `eventually` (and `within`) methods in `PollingConditions` are marked as `@ConditionBlock` and treated the same way as the `then:` and `except:` blocks.

As a (not very readable) workaround, you might replace the assignment with some "container". Here, an example with `AtomicReference` (available in JDK), but any "custom container" will be enough:

```java
    @Shared
    PollingConditions POLLING_CONDITIONS = new PollingConditions(
            timeout: 30, delay: 1.5, factor: 1.25
    )

    MyResponseContainerDto sendRequestWithRetries(String body, String uri) {
        AtomicReference<ExtractableResponse<Response>> extractedResponseContainer = 
             new AtomicReference<>()

        POLLING_CONDITIONS.eventually {
            extractedResponse.set(sendRequest(body, uri).extract())
            assert extractedResponseContainer.get().statusCode() == 200
        }

        return extractedResponseContainer.get().as(MyResponseContainerDto.class)
    }

    ValidatableResponse sendRequest(String body, String uri) {
            return RestAssured.given()
                    .contentType(JSON)
                    .body(body)
                    .when()
                    .post("/myApi" + "/" + uri)
                    .then()
                    .log().all()
    }
```

Alternatively, you might use [Awaitility](https://github.com/awaitility/awaitility/) - which is less strict in that field - to perform "active waiting". For example with the approach proposed in [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39435533).